# Pandas Pivot Table to have two rows for each group

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a table that looks like this.

```
id      process     Number1    Number2
1       a           11       343
1       b           22       121
1       c           33       889
2       a           41       317
2       b           42       997
2       c           43       761
```

What I would like is to pivot that table so it looks like this.

```
        a       b       c
1       343     121     889
1       11      22      33
2       317     997     761
2       41      42      43
```

Essentially, `process` becomes a header, and each `id` becomes an index.
One row has `Number1` and second row has `Number2`.

I have

```
fail_rate_df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='process', values='Number2', aggfunc='first')
```

which returns

```
        a       b       c
1       343     121     889
2       317     997     761
```

How can I add a second row for each id to have `Number1` also. Number2 should be first row, and `Number1` second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='process', aggfunc='first')
   .stack(level=0)
   .sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[True,False])
)
```

Output:

```
process       a    b    c
id                       
1  Number2  343  121  889
   Number1   11   22   33
2  Number2  317  997  761
   Number1   41   42   43
```